# How can I make variable change when another changes

Tags: c, pointers, variables, reference

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    unsigned int a = 2;
    unsigned int also_a = a;

    unsigned int b = 1;

    a+=b;

    printf("\n%d %d\n", a, also_a);
}
```

And this output:

```
$ ./a.out 

3 2
```

How can I have as output `3 3` ?

I am very new with C, I think I have to use pointers but I am not sure

Comment: Why do you need 2 copies. Does macro or pointer solve your problem?

Comment: use pointers. e.g. `unsigned int a = 2; unsigned int also_a = &a; ... printf( ..., a, *also_a);`

Comment: "I think I have to use pointers" - you're right. You can make `also_a` a pointer to `a`

Comment: try `#define also_a a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes pointers are what you need to use here. [Brief explanation](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-pointer/) about using pointers.

In short using pointer `also_a` you are looking at the same place in memory where variable `a` is stored. Thus when `a` changes value retrieved with `also_a` will reflect that.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned int a = 2;
    unsigned int *also_a = &a; // pointer (*) to adress (&) of variable a

    unsigned int b = 1;

    a+=b;

    printf("\n%d %d\n", a, *also_a); // de-reference (*also_a) to access value
}
```

**Result:**

```
3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointers will always help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 2;
    unsigned int *also_a = &a;
    unsigned int b = 1;
    a+=b;
    printf("\n%d %d\n", a, *also_a);
}
```

```
3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using a pointer but if you are not already using it then I assume you are not familiar with the concept. So the first solution is without using a pointer.

**Solution 1**

In this solution. a check is made before using the variable also_a to see if the value of a has changed. This is not automatic and thus might not qualify as solution. But this is the you get from me without using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    unsigned int a = 2;
    unsigned int also_a = a;
    unsigned int prev_a = a;

    unsigned int b = 1;

    a+=b;

    // also_a will be used. So check.
    if(prev_a != a) 
        also_a = a;

    printf("\n%d %d\n", a, also_a);
}
```

**Solution 2**

I will use pointers. There will be one variable and one reference to it. I will try to explain pointers after the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    unsigned int a = 2;
    unsigned int *also_a = &a; // also_a is a pointer that stores the address of a

    unsigned int b = 1;

    a+=b;

    printf("\n%d %d\n", a, *also_a);
}
```

**Explanation**

**Using variables in solution 1:** What is happening is in case of `a` and `also_a`, there are two separate variables in two different memory location. Each have their own: name, value and address. Thus there are two places where we can store our unsigned integer. Any changes that happens in `a` doesn't affect `also_a`.

To allow `also_a` to change with `a`, we can check if a has changed then assign the value of `a` to `also_a`.

**Using pointers in solution 2** In solution 2 there is only 1 variable `a`. Thus there is only one: name, value and location. `also_a` on the other hand is a special type of special type of variable called pointer which can only store the address of some other location. Thus there is only one place where we can store out unsigned integer. The second variable, which we will call pointer, "points" to this place. Thus any change made to the value stored at this place: affects the variable, and the value pointed by the pointer.

We do not need to check anything. Just change the value and all the variable and pointers get updated.

I'd recommend learning more about pointers if you have such requirements. Here is [a nice video that might help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTxHyVn0ODg). Even though it is a C++ video, it is completely relevant to C.

Comment: In **Solution 2** why did you keep the check `prev_a != a` ? This is redundant and also introducing a compilation error since `prev_a` was not declared.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I copy pasted the code form the 1st solution and missed to remove that.

Comment: No problem that's what comments are for ;) gonna give it +1 now

Answer (score 0):

Under `a += b` put `also_a = a`.

This should work.

You can also use a pointer but it's easier in this way.

You can also use `int* also_a = &a`